# Best Approach For Feature Selection

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I have more than six different table with more than 300 features(attributes). Now i am little bit confused about the right approach to select features for model building. I think about two processes

1. Pick one by one attribute and calculate the importance of it for output and add it to the data mart.
2. Take all the features from all the table and calculate their correlation and importance and remove the less important features.

Answer (score 3):

You can use forward feature selection which starts with one feature , you train a model just with one of 300 features and do this 300 times so you have trained a model with every one of them separately and choose the one which gave your model the highest accuracy, now keep that one and start to train your model with the chosen feature and another one of 299 remaining ones , so you train 299 model with 2 features, now add the one among 299 which gave you the highest accuracy accompanying the previously selected one. now you have 2 features. you go on like this to choose the **k** best features you want, 100 for example. be aware this method will not give you the optimal set of features, for example two features may work very good together but none of them has a significant impact on the decision boundary alone so none of them will be selected.also it is a painfully long approach. there is backward feature selection also which you start will all of them, all 300 , and remove one by one the less important feature base on the error you get by removing them.

my advice is to use feature extraction methods instead. use [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) from scikit-learn. it is as simple as just importing it and calling it!! done. but make sure to normalize your data before using PCA, you can use [StandardScalar](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) for that matter.

Answer (score 3):

300 features are too much for your model building process.

You can use algorithms like xgboost and random forest as they have capabilities of 
finding features importances.

You can sort your features based on the feature importances and remove the ones which have very less importance.This will make your model less complex.

Answer (score 1):

Another modeling option you might want consider is [lasso-regularized regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)). In this approach, the coefficients of some features are shrunk to zero, which has the effect of essentially doing variable selection as part of the modeling process. It's possible to use it for either continuous or discrete binary target variables and is particularly useful in situations where the number of features is close to, equal to, or greater than the number of observations.